# Pyspark : Exception in reading JSON data containing backslash

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having an issue reading JSON from Spark SQL code in PYSPARK. JSON object is in the format as shown below. There are some struct datatypes having `\\` and when I try to read this data I'm getting an exception.

{ "SalesManager":"{\"Email":\"abc@xyz.com\"}", "colb":"somevalue" }

I tried to add `'serialization.format' = '1','ignore.malformed.json' = 'true'`, but it did not help.

Exception:

> raceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line
> 380, in show
> print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> line 1257, in **call**   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
> return f(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line
> 328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling o365.showString. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
> in stage 5.0 (TID 283, ip-10-0-1-92.ec2.internal, executor 119):
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data is not JSONObject  but
> java.lang.String with value {"Email":"abc@xyz.com"}
> at org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.JsonStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(JsonStructObjectInspector.java:73)

Comment: It seems the sample you shared is not in the correct JSON format. I guess it should be like `{
"SalesManager":"{\"Email\":\"abc@xyz.com\"}",
"colb":"somevalue"
}`
and secondly, you want to ignore such cases (which have extra `\\` character) or want to transform them into the correct format?

Comment: sorry, typo in my input, the correct format is like here - { "SalesManager":"{\"Email\":\"abc@xyz.com\"}", "colb":"somevalue" } . I need to ignore such occurances

Comment: Ok, you can edit the question and modify the format as well. Did you tried setting `.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")`?

Comment: Sure, I will modify the question. I don't want to use dropmalformed. What I am trying to do is I am reading from json and wrting back to a different s3 bucket as "json" . However while writing it is writing some fields with "\" considering it as StringType() . Either I wan't to avoid writing with "\" OR read the json containing with "\" and ignore the special characters.

Comment: Ok, I see, in the struct definition what is the type of the field `SalesManager`? I guess you have defined it as String while it should not be defined as String. I think you should define a nested type for that key (`SalesManager`), which only has the field `Email`. So when Spark converts the DataFrame to JSON, can infer that the value of the `SalesManager` is JsonObject and not String and will not add the `\\` character.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you share a single line example of the input json.